# JNI error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception, dropwizard, apache-commons

Error log:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/text/StrSubstitutor
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.text.StrSubstitutor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 7 more
```

> I know that people have asked this question before but none of them are using the Dropwizard framework.

Here is what I have tried:

- Different versions of Dropwizard using the pom.xml,
- Adding commons-lang and commons-text don't seem to fix it, though commons-text makes it throw a different error,
- Restarting my computer.

It is a pretty involved `pom.xml` file which I am not comfortable sharing...

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible, that you compile with a newer version (like Java 8) and run it with an older version (Java 7)? If yes, check the Path. (1) 
Another thing could be, that the apache libraries are compiled with a more recent version.

(1) Try comparing the output of `java --version` and `javac --version`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, JC. 
`javac -version`: `javac 1.8.0_231` and `java -version`: `java version "1.8.0_231"`.